# How to make a list view of the places marked in maps?

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm working on Travel app, I'm locating nearest places on the map. Could you please help me in making a dynamic listview of those places getting located on map?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "located on map"? What is data source of those places?

Answer (score 3):

First of all use a **webservice**!

Make an account here : http://www.geonames.org/login
Enable webservices access on your account

After that look for this webservice: **[findNearby](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearby)**

It outputs all places that are nearby a **lat / long coördinate**. A free account has its limits ( 3000 requests a day i think ) but its the **best you can get** !

[Example output (JSON)](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?formatted=true&lat=48.865618158309374&lng=2.344207763671875&fclass=P&fcode=PPLA&fcode=PPL&fcode=PPLC&username=demo&style=full)
[Example output (XML)](http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=48.865618158309374&lng=2.344207763671875&fclass=P&fcode=PPLA&fcode=PPL&fcode=PPLC&username=demo&style=full)

Check out these **tutorials** on how to get XML or JSON data into a listview:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-series-from-sql-php-to-xml-json-to-android-listview/